# help understanding MonoTouch crash log

Tags: xamarin.ios

My MonoTouch app  (release build) is crashing randomly and I'm getting this in the crash log. Unfortunately, I don't see anything useful related to my app. It looks like it's down deep in the bowels of MonoTouch and iOS.

I'm running this on an iPhone 3G with OS 3.1.2.

Can anyone help me understand what this crash log means?

---

```
Incident Identifier: 222781AB-0F7C-4E1D-9E10-6EE946D6C320
CrashReporter Key:   0ee985a48f32f63b7e50536870f06a1ab4122600
Process:         MyApp_iOS [593]
Path:            /var/mobile/Applications/095A615B-2F9B-4A84-B0E3-EF1246915594/MyApp_iOS.app/MyApp_iOS
Identifier:      MyApp_iOS
Version:         ??? (???)
Code Type:       ARM (Native)
Parent Process:  launchd [1]

Date/Time:       2011-03-24 13:04:18.479 -0700
OS Version:      iPhone OS 3.1.2 (7D11)
Report Version:  104

Exception Type:  EXC_CRASH (SIGABRT)
Exception Codes: 0x00000000, 0x00000000
Crashed Thread:  0

Thread 0 Crashed:
0   dyld                              0x2fe125b2 ImageLoaderMachOCompressed::findExportedSymbol(char const*, ImageLoader const**) const + 58
1   dyld                              0x2fe0dcd6 ImageLoaderMachO::findExportedSymbol(char const*, bool, ImageLoader const**) const + 30
2   dyld                              0x2fe0ee6e ImageLoaderMachOClassic::resolveUndefined(ImageLoader::LinkContext const&, macho_nlist const*, bool, bool, ImageLoader const**) + 434
3   dyld                              0x2fe10250 ImageLoaderMachOClassic::doBindLazySymbol(unsigned long*, ImageLoader::LinkContext const&) + 212
4   dyld                              0x2fe037ae dyld::bindLazySymbol(mach_header const*, unsigned long*) + 94
5   dyld                              0x2fe0e29c stub_binding_helper_interface + 12
6   MyApp_iOS                         0x0071a754 mono_handle_native_sigsegv (mini-exceptions.c:1762)
7   MyApp_iOS                         0x0073d900 sigabrt_signal_handler (mini-posix.c:155)
8   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x0008e81c _sigtramp + 28
9   libSystem.B.dylib                 0x00033904 semaphore_wait_signal + 4
10  libSystem.B.dylib                 0x00003ca8 pthread_mutex_lock + 440
11  MyApp_iOS                         0x0088e76c GC_lock (pthread_support.c:1679)
12  MyApp_iOS                         0x00884970 GC_malloc_atomic (malloc.c:259)
13  MyApp_iOS                         0x007f26e4 mono_object_new_ptrfree_box (object.c:3996)


[... there are 10 active threads but I've only included the one that crashed]


Thread 0 crashed with ARM Thread State:
    r0: 0x00000000    r1: 0x0097dc97      r2: 0x344d7c3c      r3: 0x344dd2bd
    r4: 0x344dd2bd    r5: 0x00005681      r6: 0x0097dc97      r7: 0x2fffe6d8
    r8: 0x344e7f34    r9: 0x00000001     r10: 0x0000007f     r11: 0x0097dc97
    ip: 0x344d8e4c    sp: 0x2fffe658      lr: 0x2fe0dcdd      pc: 0x2fe125b2
  cpsr: 0x20000030
```

Comment: Best to have a reproducible test case, the stack trace does not give many hints

Answer (score 5):

Another diagnosis option I've found is to:

1. Hook up AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException
2. Put a try-catch around your entire "static void Main()" method

In both causes write the exception to Console.WriteLine().

Then run your app, open XCode and open the console window for your device while it's plugged in.  Then cause the crash.  You should be able to see a decent C# stack trace of the exception.

This has helped me fix many issues that only happen when running in release on the device.